# Using Magento API(REST) via IXMLHTTPRequest COM Object

Tags: api, rest-api, oauth

We have downloaded Magento Community Edition ver 1.9.1.0 and installed it in XAMPP ( PHP Version 5.5.15 ). Also we have included "php_oauth.dll" in php.ini and copied file(dll) to PHP/ext directory.

Our problem is that we cannot access to for example "magentohost/api/rest/products"(it throws "Access Denied"), in a result we cannot connect to oAuth for getting Accesss Token.
In API documentation the examples are only in PHP. But we have throuble with it, because we are using "XMLHTTPRequest.6.0" COM object and with it we are able only
to GET/POST on specified host and retrive data, not more.

We have no library to use "OAuth" object as shown in documentation.

Our question is to clarifiy where is the end point of oAuth in Magento. URL that we need to POST data ( secret and key ) to get Access Token.

And Also if it is possible give us example code.

Thanks.